# Azure Devops Powershell Variables Odd Issues

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a 2 stage build pipeline defined in YAML. In job #1, I execute a powershell script and set the output like so:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable;isOutput=true;]$ComplexObjectArraylist"
```

Before outputting the variable, I convert it to a single line of json and then call .ToString() as I was encountering some odd serialization problems before.

In the second job, I am also executing a Powershell script that takes the variable from above as a parameter and this is where it gets weird...

Upon receiving the variable I immediately executed:

```
$myVariable = $myVariable | ConvertFrom-Json
```

However, I would later encounter issues trying to reference specific properties of this object. It would **not** write to my console unless I did a foreach write-host $item, which I believe is a known "issue" of outputting complex objects in devops log.

I ended up fixing this by simply creating a brand new variable called $test and ran the exact same code as before:

```
$test = $myVariable | ConvertFrom-Json
```

After setting the $test variable, I could appropriately reference my properties. Why did I have to do this?

Comment: Could you please share a minimum YAML pipeline that can reproduce the issue you encountered? It can help us more to understand how the output variable is passed across stages/jobs(regular job/deployment job) and how output variable is defined/consumed in the downstream job. By the way, what is the json contents look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have just create a sample yaml of stage + json string + json object pass

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        $jsonStr = '{"name":"John","age":30,"car":"test"}'
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myStageVal;isOutput=true]'$jsonStr'"
      name: MyOutputVar

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    variables:
      myStageAVar: $[stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['MyOutputVar.myStageVal']]
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host "test 1:"
        Write-Host "print json string: $(myStageAVar)"
        $jsobObj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $(myStageAVar)
        Write-Host "convert to object and print item: $($jsobObj.name), $($jsobObj.age)"

        Write-Host "test 2:"
        $myStageAVar = $(myStageAVar) | ConvertFrom-Json
        Write-Host "convert to object and print item: $($myStageAVar.name), $($myStageAVar.age)"
```

be careful to the **'$jsonStr'**, should be have the single quotes, otherwise will fail. hope this can help u.

[image]

Comment: That's not the case for my pipeline. I am only using single quotes when calling the 2nd PowerShell script. When setting the output variable, single quotes is definitely not needed.

Comment: @DataDill my bad, I misunderstand your case. but I don't know why you can refer the setVariable variable "myVariable" using $myVariable instead of $(myVariable )

Answer (score 0):

We should probably use single quote to make sure the output variable is processed as a string.

Kindly refer to the sample YAML below.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
- stage: stageA
  jobs:
  - job: jobA1
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $object = @{
              name = "John"
              age = 30
              city = "New York"
          }
          $ComplexObjectArraylist = $object | ConvertTo-Json -compress

          Write-Host "ComplexObjectArraylist string is $ComplexObjectArraylist"

          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVariable;isOutput=true;]$ComplexObjectArraylist"
      name: SetOutputVar
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host SetOutputVar.myVariable is '$(SetOutputVar.myVariable)'

- stage: stageB
  dependsOn: stageA
  jobs:
  - job: jobB1
    variables:
      myVariable: $[ stageDependencies.stageA.jobA1.outputs['SetOutputVar.myVariable'] ]
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host myVariable is '$(myVariable)'
          $myVariable = '$(myVariable)' | ConvertFrom-Json
          Write-Host $myVariable.name
```

[image]